# Grails Serve Static Contents from WebServer from ApplicationResources.groovy

Tags: grails, webserver

We have a web server for static files (css/js/images). We obtain the war from the Grails command and delete the static web-app contents from application (in build.xml). I thought resources will be redirected to static/js/ or static/css/ but it complains that js/ or /css/ cannot be found.

We don't want to have duplicates under application and web-server. How to force Grails to look at external directory in ApplicationResources.groovy?

The Web server overrides static contents only if files are already present under Application.

Comment: Note:We are using ApplicationResources.groovy for static resources.

Answer (score 3):

Use below configuration in `Config.groovy`:

```
grails.resources.work.dir = "path/for/static/assets/in/web/server"
```

Refer the [configuration page of resources plugin for details](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-resources/guide/9.%20Configuration.html). However, in future, if you decide to migrate to use [asset-pipeline plugin](https://grails.org/plugin/asset-pipeline) instead of resources plugin then use below configuration:

```
grails.assets.url = "path/for/static/assets/in/web/server"
```

Refer [docs for details](http://bertramdev.github.io/asset-pipeline/guide/configuration.html).

Comment: By default grails initally looks in the application base directory and for some reason it requires the static files to be there.If present anyways ,files from web server overrides the one under app..If not file is not present under App,it complains that file not found /js/etc.....